# not able to type password

Tags: password, password-recovery

when I installed Ubuntu the passwords didn't show no matter what I typed. So I just typed random letters so many times then I hit enter. now when I am trying to reset the password I don't know how and it still shows nothing when I type the password

I typed this to change the password:

```
$ sudo passwd my_username
```

then it showed:

```
[sudo] password for my_username:
sorry, try again
```

I am new to programming and I am just 13 please tell me how to fix it